# Search the first and second variable (with spaces and special character like $) using awk

Tags: bash, awk

I have a dataset where i need to search for the 2 variables in it. Both vars should be present, otherwise ignore them.

inputfile.txt:

```
IFRA-SCN-01001B.brz.com Tower Sales
IFRA-SCN-01001B.brz.com Z$
IFRA-SCN-01001B.brz.com Pre-code$
IFRA-SCN-01001B.brz.com Technical Stuff
IFRA-SCN-01001B.brz.com expired$
IFRA-SCN-01001B.brz.com AA$
IFRA-SCN-01002B.brz.com Build Docs
IFRA-SCN-01002B.brz.com Build Docs
```

BigFile.txt:

```
\\IFRA-SCN-01001B.brz.com\ABC PTR,John.Mayn@brz.com
\\IFRA-SCN-01001B.brz.com\ABC PTR,John.Mayn@brz.com
\\IFRA-SCN-01001B.brz.com\bitshare\DOC TRIGGER,Peter.Salez@brz.com
\\IFRA-SCN-01001B.brz.com\bitshare,Peter.Salez@brz.com
\\IFRA-SCN-01001B.brz.com\bitshare\PFM FRAUD,Peter.Salez@brz.com
\\IFRA-SCN-01001B.brz.com\Build Docs,Arlan.Boynoz@brz.com
\\IFRA-SCN-01001B.brz.com\Build Docs,Arlan.Boynoz@brz.com
\\IFRA-SCN-01002B.brz.com\Build Docs,Arlan.Boynoz@brz.com
\\IFRA-SCN-01002B.brz.com\Build Docs,Arlan.Boynoz@brz.com
```

it is working if i use the actual string but not if assigned to a variable.

```
[root@brzmgmt]$ awk '/Build Docs/{ok=1;s=NR}ok && NR<=s+2 && /IFRA-SCN-01002B.brz.com/{print $0}' BigFile.txt
\\IFRA-SCN-01002B.brz.com\Build Docs,Arlan.Boynoz@brz.com
\\IFRA-SCN-01002B.brz.com\Build Docs,Arlan.Boynoz@brz.com


while read -r zz; do
        var1=`echo $zz | print '{print $1}'`
        var2=`echo $zz | print '{print $2}'`
        awk '/$var2/{ok=1;s=NR}ok && NR<=s+2 && /$va1/{print $0}' BigFile.txt <--NOT_WORKING
        awk -v a=$var1 b=$var2 '/$b//{ok=1;s=NR}ok && NR<=s+2 && /$a/{print $0}' BigFile.txt <--NOT_WORKING
        fi
done < inputfile.txt
```

any idea what am i missing?

```
awk '/$var2/{ok=1;s=NR}ok && NR<=s+2 && /$va1/{print $0}' BigFile.txt <--NOT_WORKING
awk -v a=$var1 -v b=$var2 '/$b/{ok=1;s=NR}ok && NR<=s+2 && /$a/{print $0}' BigFile.txt <--NOT_WORKING
```

Comment: `/.../` expects regex. You can use `match($0,"...")` for fixed string.

Comment: Are the values supposed to be on same line? Or anywhere in file? Or something else? Why do you test `NR<=s+2` ?

Comment: In `awk '/$var2/....'` you are missing that shell and awk variables are very different and that shell variables do not expand when placed between single-quotes. In `awk -v a=$var1 -v b=$var2 '/$b/...'` it looks like you are missing that `$b` would seek the **field** number represented by `b`. Rather you want `b` instead of `$b`. Also `echo $zz | print '{print $1}'` makes no sense. `echo` is fine, but `print '{print $1}'` is confusing at best.

Comment: You shouldn't be using a shell `while read` loop at all, you can/should do what you want in a single call to awk. See [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice). After accepting an answer to the question you asked about what's wrong with your syntax, if you ask a new question about how to improve your script then we can help you with that.

Comment: @EdMorton, apologies for not having a good script. wasn't really my forte, but helping myself day by day to improve.

Comment: No need to apologize, we're all learning every day, I'm just giving you a heads up about some issues beyond those you specifically asked about so you can follow up on them if you like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see a number of problems here. First, where you split the fields from inputfile.txt with

```
while read -r zz; do
    var1=`echo $zz | print '{print $1}'`
    var2=`echo $zz | print '{print $2}'`
```

When the line is something like "IFRA-SCN-01002B.brz.com Build Docs", `var1` will be set correctly, but `var2` will only get "Build", not "Build Docs". I assume you want the latter? If so, I'd let `read` do the splitting for you:

```
while read -r var1 var2
```

...which will automatically include any "extra fields" (e.g. "Docs") in the last variable. If you *don't* want the full remainder of the line, just add an extra variable to hold anything beyond the second field:

```
while read -r var1 var2 ignoredstuff
```

See [BashFAQ #1: How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (and/or field-by-field)?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)

As for the `awk` commands, the first one doesn't work because the shell doesn't expand variables inside single-quotes. You could switch to double-quotes, but then you'd have to escape `$0` to keep the shell from expanding *that*, and you'd also have to worry about the search strings possibly including awk syntax, and it's generally a mess. The second method, with `-v`, is a lot better, but you still have to fix a couple of things.

In the `-v a=$var1 b=$var2` part, you should double-quote the variables so the shell doesn't split them if they contain spaces (like "Build Docs"): `-v a="$var1" -v b="$var2"`. You should pretty much always double-quote variable references to prevent problems like this.

Also, the way you use those `a` and `b` variables in the `awk` command isn't right. `$` in awk doesn't mean "substitute a variable" like it does in shell, it generally means "get a field by number" (e.g. `$2` gets the second field, and `$(x+2)` gets the `x`-plus-second field). Also, in a `/.../` pattern, variables (and field references) don't get substituted anyway. So what you probably want instead of `/$a` and `/$b/` is `$0~a` and `$0~b` (note that `~` is awk's regex match operator).

So the command should be something like this:

```
awk -v a="$var1" -v b="$var2" '$0~b{ok=1;s=NR}ok && NR<=s+2 && $0~a{print $0}' BigFile.txt
```

Except... you might not want that, because it treats the strings as regular expressions rather than plain strings. So the `.` characters in "IFRA-SCN-01001B.brz.com" will match any single character, and the `$` in "Pre-code$" will be treated as an end-of-string anchor rather than a literal character. If you just want them matched as literal strings, use e.g. `index($0,b)` instead:

```
awk -v a="$var1" -v b="$var2" 'index($0,b){ok=1;s=NR}ok && NR<=s+2 && index($0,a){print $0}' BigFile.txt
```

I'd also recommend running your scripts through [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) to catch common mistakes and bad practices.

Finally, I have to ask what's up with all the `ok` and `s` stuff. That looks like it's going to insert some weird inter-record dependencies that don't make any sense. Also, if the fields are always going to be in that same order, would a `grep` search be simpler?

Comment: I've taken and read all your suggestion. I've been really practicing the use of awk for my data manipulation. I know it can be done using `grep` but since there is other stuff that I need to insert hence the use of `awk`. 

is it safe to say that in case I have a variable to use, I still need to redefine it again as part of the awk command?

Comment: @gafm There are other ways to access shell variables in `awk`, but copying them into `awk` variables with `-v awkvar="$shellvar"` is almost always the best. See ["How do I use shell variables in an awk script?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075671/how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script)

Answer (score 3):

Your code is:

```
while read -r zz; do
        var1=`echo $zz | print '{print $1}'`
        var2=`echo $zz | print '{print $2}'`
        awk '/$var2/{ok=awk1;s=NR}ok && NR<=s+2 && /$va1/{print $0}' BigFile.txt <--NOT_WORKING
        awk -v a=$var1 b=$var2 '/$b//{ok=1;s=NR}ok && NR<=s+2 && /$a/{print $0}' BigFile.txt <--NOT_WORKING
        fi
done < inputfile.txt
```

I won't address the logic of the code (eg. you should probably be using `match($0,"...")` instead of `/.../`, and I don't know what the test `NR<=s+2` is for) but here are some syntax and efficiency issues:

- You appear to want to read a line of whitespace-delimited text into two variables. This is more simply done with just: `read -r var1 var2` or `read -r var1 var2 junk`
- `print` is not a standard shell command. Perhaps this is meant to be an awk script (`awk '{print $1}'`, etc)? But just use simple read instead.
- Single-quotes prevent variable expansion so, inside the script argument passed to awk, `/$var/` will literally look for dollar, v, a, r. Pass variables using awk's `-v` option as you do in the second awk line.
- Each variable passed to awk needs a separate `-v` option.
- awk does not use `$name` to reference variable values, simply `name`. To use a variable as a regex, just use it in the right place: eg. `$0 ~ name`.

So:

```
while read -r var1 var2 junk; do
    # quote variables to prevent globbing, word-splitting, etc
    awk -v a="$var1" -v "$var2" '
        $0 ~ var2 { ok=1; s=NR }
        ok && NR<=s+2 && $0 ~ var1 ; # print is default action
    ' BigFile.txt
done <inputfile.txt
```

---

Note that the more var1/var2 you want to check, the longer the runtime ( O(mn) : m sets of var1/var2 and n lines of input to check ). There may be more efficient algorithms if the problem is better-specified.

Comment: thanks for pointing that out. I'll be very specific with my requirement next time. But thank you. Had re-written my script and had taken your suggestion.